# How to configure nack/node on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

Does any one Has every configure [nack](https://github.com/josh/nack) for the Rails Projects I happen to tried the dummy code

```
var http = require('http'); 
var nack = require('nack');
var app = nack.createProcess("/home/viren/myapp/config.ru");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {   app.proxy(req, res); }).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

but it reported me with the following error

> events.js:94
>
> throw new Error('addListener only takes instances of Function');
>
> ^ Error: addListener only takes instances of Function
>
> at BufferedRequest. (events.js:94:11)
>
> at Process. (/home/viren/node_modules/nack/lib/process.js:257:21)
>
> at Process.proxy (/home/viren/node_modules/nack/lib/process.js:3:63)
>
> at Server. (/home/viren/simple.proxy.js:7:7)
>
> at Server.emit (events.js:67:17)
>
> at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1124:12)
>
> at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:108:31)
>
> at Socket.ondata (http.js:1019:22)
>
> at Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27)
>
> at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)

here is my custom rack-file

```
require "config/environment"

use Rails::Rack::LogTailer
use ActionDispatch::Static
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the source at node_modules/nack/lib/process.js:257 nack is expecting app.proxy to have a signature of app.proxy(req, res, next) with is a common idiom with connect apps.  In connect, calling next("some value") is a convention as most apps have a catch all error handler at the bottom of the middleware chain.  Since your not using connect, just create your own error handler.

I also created a pull request, so hopefully using next will be optional in the future.  https://github.com/josh/nack/pull/25

```
var http = require('http'); var nack = require('nack');

var app = nack.createProcess("/home/viren/myapp/config.ru");

http.createServer(function (req, res) { app.proxy(req, res, logNackError); }).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");

function logNackError(err) {
  console.log('nack error:', err);
}
```

Comment: Sure I will try this. would be very helpful if you can actual document it